# Problem in executing SSIS Package through an asp.net c# application

Tags: ssis, package

i am having a problem in executing the SSIS package through an asp.net application. i'm using c#. every time i run the package through web, i think the package is not disposed properly so until and unless i stop the application the package won't execute...i am not able to dispose or unload the package...

i'm geeting errors like

'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\CustomMarshalers\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CustomMarshalers.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The result of the expression ""EXEC " +  @[User::vRowData]" on property "SqlStatementSource" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.
: Package Execution results: {0}

here is my code

Application app = new Application();
                //Package package = app.LoadPackage("D:\ChipRewards_WorkingFolder\ChipRewards\Codebase\HeathPlan\Common\Trunk\SSIS Package\ETL_WorkFlow\ETL_WorkFlow\DataImport.dtsx", null);
                //package.ImportConfigurationFile("D:\ChipRewards_WorkingFolder\ChipRewards\Codebase\HeathPlan\Common\Trunk\SSIS Package\ETL_WorkFlow\ETL_WorkFlow\ETLConfig.dtsConfig");

```
            using (Package package = app.LoadPackage("D:\\ChipRewards_Test_Environment\\Test\\ETL_WorkFlow\\ETL_WorkFlow\\DataImport.dtsx", null, true))
            {
                package.ImportConfigurationFile("D:\\ChipRewards_Test_Environment\\Test\\ETL_WorkFlow\\ETL_WorkFlow\\ETLConfig.dtsConfig");

                DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();

                if (result == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
                    {

                        Debug.WriteLine("Package Execution results: {0}", local_DtsError.Description.ToString());
                    }
                }
                package.Dispose();
            }
```

i don't know what's happening...i would be very thankful if anyone could help me solve the problem...

Thanks,
Antiflag

Comment: why are you using package.Dispose(); inside using block? you can set package = null after using ends, if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this bit:-

> The result of the expression ""EXEC " + @[User::vRowData]" on property "SqlStatementSource" cannot be written to the property.

It sounds like there is a problem with the configuration file and an expression you are trying to load.